# Unable to login to openlitespeed Wordpress backend and not receiving Password reset email

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, passwords, openlitespeed

I have a wordpress site deployed on GCP, but I am unable to login because I forgot the password. Also I am not receiving the password reset email.

Please help.

Regards
Sid

Answer (score 0):

For the not receiving email issue, it might be due to Google does not allow access to port 25 from a Google instance for security reasons.

I'd recommend you reset the password from the PHPMyAdmin.

1. log in to the PHPMyAdmin
2. Find the wp_users entry under WordPress DataBase
3. "Edit" the user, replace the value in the user_pass field with your new password